# Displaying many rows using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am retrieving data from database using JSON.The problem is when I try to retrieve the entire rows nothing get displayed.If I display a single row it is successful.How do I display multiple rows.Am using `while` loop .
The code am trying to display multiple rows is :

```html
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","?l:@CoLo2016//?[$^*@!(><)my~~~server~~2000]1620","test") or die("error in server");
  $sql="SELECT * FROM test";
  $qry=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($qry)){
    
    $table_data[]= array("First Name"=$row['fname'],"Last Name"=$row['lname']);
    
    
  }
echo json_encode($table_data);
?>
```

Any guide please?

Comment: A good IDE would really help you catch syntax errors like this one.

Comment: where is the syntax error?I have tried => instead of = but still not working.Am using sublime text IDE

Comment: Sublime may be cute, but it's still a text editor, not an IDE. It just doesn't do much without proper plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you need to use the `=>` assignment operator rather than `=`

```
$table_data[]= array( "First Name" => $row['fname'], "Last Name" => $row['lname'] );

<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","?l:@CoLo2016//?[$^*@!(><)my~~~server~~2000]1620","test") or die("error in server");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM test";
    $qry=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

   /*
      using `fetch_assoc` to return an assiciative array
      rather then numerically indexed
   */ 
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $qry ) ){
        $table_data[]=array( "First Name"=>$row['fname'],"Last Name"=>$row['lname'] );
    }

    echo json_encode( $table_data );
?>
```

Comment: Looking at the manual ( never before used `mysqli_fetch_row` ) it suggests that the returned data is in a numerically indexed form rather than associative array. If you have just two columns in the `test` table then it should be relatively painless to use `$row[0]` and `$row[1]` - if there are more then perhaps use a different method to retrieve the rows.

Comment: yah I have more columns